# Showing cards with one player all-in but other player active

Tags: nlhe, rules, tournament, all-in

Situation: NLHE tournament, 3 players on turn

- P1 goes all-in
- P2 (has P1 covered) calls
- P1 does not realize that P3 (also has P1 covered) is still active and
  shows his cards, P2 does the same.

In the concrete situation it was ruled that P1 and P2 are still live although P2 wasn't allowed agressive actions, but the floorman looked like he was not completely sure on this one. Is this a common ruling for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this in the wsop tournament rules:

> 110. Exposing Cards and Proper Folding: A participant exposing his or her cards with action pending will incur a penalty, but will not have
>        a dead hand. The penalty will begin at the end of the hand. All participants at the table are entitled to see the exposed card(s). When
>        folding, cards should be pushed forward low to the table, not deliberately exposed or tossed high (“helicoptered”).

So the hand should have continued normaly with P3 making his decision. If the flop was to be dealt, P2 would have to play with cards face up.

Comment: Nice to know how one of the big players handles this.

Comment: Think of the funny situations this could create on the flop if p3 calls :-)

Comment: Can you mark this question as answered please :)

Comment: I am looking if there are some more references. If there is none in the next dass, I will accept this.